# Using lucene and wildcards at the beginning of a word

Tags: c#, lucene, wildcard

I have a problem using Lucene.NET 2.9.4. Maybe anybody can help me.

Currently when the user enter the word ***open*** i will change the search therm automatically to ****open****. I have set QueryParser.SetAllowLeadingWildcard(true);  i know, this can be expensive...

My Text is:

"***You can use the menu file / open to edit an existing document***"

When i use ***open**** or ***open*** as a search term, lucene find the text.

When i use ****open**** lucene doesn't find the text.

Why not? What is problem with a leading wildcard? I want to find the search term on start, at the end and in the middle of a word.

i want to search for ***open*** and...

- foo bar               =>  is not a match
- opening foo bar       =>  is a match
- testopen foo bar      =>  is a match
- testopening foo bar   =>  is a match

How can i do this?

Comment: I too have experienced some unexpected/inconsistent results when using Lucene, but more often than not they are caused by mismatching the storage and query analyzers. Are you sure you're data was committed to Lucene using the same analyzer that you're attempting to search it with?

Comment: Yes, i'm sure. I only use a StandardAnalyzer in my program           

....... new StandardAnalyzer(Lucene.Net.Util.Version.LUCENE_29, this.StopWordFile);

Answer (score 1):

Per default leading wildcards are disabled, but with Lucene >=2.1 there is a way to enable this.

> Leading wildcards (e.g. *ook) are not supported by the QueryParser by
>   default. As of Lucene 2.1, they can be enabled by calling
>   QueryParser.setAllowLeadingWildcard( true ). Note that this can be an
>   expensive operation: it requires scanning the list of tokens in the
>   index in its entirety to look for those that match the pattern.

see:[Lucene FAQ](http://wiki.apache.org/lucene-java/LuceneFAQ?highlight=%28leading%29%7C%28wildcard%29#What_wildcard_search_support_is_available_from_Lucene.3F)

Comment: Please read the third line of my first post again... You will see, i know that already! But i don't know why a leading wildcard means "one or more" charactes and a finishing wildcard means "zero or more".

Answer (score 1):

2 things:

1) I would verify that [Luke](http://code.google.com/p/luke/) gives you the same results as your query code.

2) Does "testopening foo bar" work or fail?